# woocommerce variations - theme conflict problems

Tags: jquery, css, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am hopeful that someone much more knowledgeable than myself would be willing to spend a few minutes and help with with a small issue. Let me start by saying that I'm not able to verify my sites theme because we had a developer migrate our site a few years back and I do't have access to that purchase info from the QODE theme 'Central' So I can't even submit a help ticket with them without the code. I can't find another way to get in touch with them about the issue so I'm posting here with hopes someone will come to my rescue.

My problem is enabling the variations on woocommerce products. If you check out https://www.bikeengines.com/shop/belt-tension-knob/​​ - you can see the issue on this test product I've setup. If you watch close you can see that when the page first starts loading that the dropdown selection menu is there - but as the page finishes loading- it kills the menu from loading in the box and the selection  window is blank. In the product dashboard there is a 'custom field' section and it has 'slide_template' in one of the fields but I don't know what it's for or it's it related in any way.

There is 1 jQuery error on the page but I am not sure if its related - I'm very inexperienced with all of this. I've spent the last few weeks updating the old plugins and trying to fix the various bugs that introduces. I've done well with everything up to this point and could use an experts opinion.

We had them customize the 'checkout' in woocommerce paypal pro gateway so that it defaults to the credit card instead of paypal - but that's he only code I can think of that may be effecting the variations.

Last resort was trying to update all the plugins on our staging test site but the problem still persists. Woocommerce tells me there's theme conflicts on the main dashboard - but I can't get it solved. :(

Any help would be deeply appreciated,
Vaughn

Comment: this is the error I've narrowed it down to fix the issue. I used a plugin on my staging site and it fixed it - but broke the entire site, lol. So I need a little help resolving this without messing things up.      default_dynamic.php?ver=4.9.8:161 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at default_dynamic.php?ver=4.9.8:161
(anonymous) @ default_dynamic.php?ver=4.9.8:161
autoptimize_51c7f295052beb72a9b75e651555a13f.js:8 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

Comment: it's at the end of the code:  }

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";

 showContactMap();
});

function showContactMap() {
 "use strict";

 if($j("#map_canvas").length > 0){
  initialize();
  codeAddress('');
 }
}


var no_ajax_pages = [];
var root = 'https://www.bikeengines.com/';
var parallax_speed = 1;


  no_ajax_pages.push('');

Answer (score 0):

closing and re-titling with hopes that it will get some traction with the right title... now that I'm on the right track with what the issue is. (Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined)